# Spring Boot throws ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS in Chrome

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cas

I have one application that is using Spring Boot 1.2.5 and CAS 4.0.4.

When I open it via Firefox works fine, redirecting the user to CAS login page if the user is not authenticated yet and after authentication CAS redirects to my application.

Sadly in Chrome throws the exception "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" when the ticket is generated, and browser dies trying to go back to my application.

I noticed if use "/" after the context root name it works fine even in Chrome.

Is there any reason for it?

`https://domain:9122/context  -->> Shows error in Chrome, but works in Firefox
https://domain:9122/context/ -->> Works fine everywhere (even in Chrome)`

How can I inform Spring Boot to work with slash after context name?

I'd appreciate any help.

Cheers,

Comment: Hey, did u find any solution for this thread? I just got the exact same problem. Weirdly I got 2 environments, and the problem only happens in one of them. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I solved... my CAS had a configuration issue about the url's set

Comment: I solved mine, but it's related to tomcat version, I rolled back from tomcat 8.0.30 to 8.0.26 and everything was fine. Can you tell me what about in your CAS conf was wrong so I can double check mine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

for some reason you can't use # in the path. replace for other character/word and will works.